# I have 2 csv files with historical crypto data, how can I delete the rows that only exist in one file and absent in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, cryptocurrency

I have 2 csv files with historical data of 2 cryptos. And I need to calculate a historical difference of their prices. The problem is, there is some data missing. For example in **file A** there is data for *2023.12.15 00:31* but in **file B** there is no data for that time. And in this case I want to delete data for *2023.12.15 00:31* from **file A**, so that data is absent in each file.

I've read the pandas docs (I'm using python), searched for similiar questions but didn't find anything that looks like solution for my case. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: A [mre] is missing, but you probably want an inner `merge`.

Comment: @mozway Thanks, that's actually what I needed